# for loop fails to load the last iteration in geocode using javascript

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm facing a problem for last 2 days with geocode in javascript. I'm getting the location from DB using php. and i passed the data to javascript variable. the data is below. i stored this data in the variable "locations"

```
[['São Paulo, Brazil', 'Sky Ferreira @ Cine Joia - Sao Paulo, Brazil','314','15'],['Rua dos Ingleses, 209 - Morro dos Ingleses', 'Se Essa Rua Fosse Minha - Espetáculo de Brincar','1','31'],['São Bernardo do Campo - São Paulo, Brazil', 'Se Essa Rua Fosse Minha - Espetáculo de Brincar','2','31'],['Cine Joia - Praça Carlos Gomes, Se, São Paulo, Brazil', '::: LOBO + VESPAS MANDARINAS @ CINE JOIA  :::','310','11'],['Rio de Janeiro, Centro, Rio, Brazil', '#GRIND - FESTA OFICIAL DE 16 ANOS @ALCA','315','16'],['Rua Vergueiro, Paraíso, São Paulo, Brazil', 'Se Essa Rua Fosse Minha - Espetáculo de Brincar','23','31'],['Clube da Aeronautica, Centro, Rio - Rio de Janeiro, Brazil', '#GRIND - BATALHA POP vs ROCK GARBAGE vs BRITNEY -  DOMINGUEIRA MAIS ALTERNATIVA @ ALCA','316','35'],['Santa Catarina, Brazil', 'Nene no Cassino do Chacrinha! Djs Mauro Borges, Nene, Ricardo Motta.','317','36'],['Rua dos Ingleses, 209 - Morro dos Ingleses', 'St. Vincent - Brazilian Tour','308','31'],['Divinópolis - Minas Gerais, Brazil', 'LANCAMENTO OFICIAL DO NOVO CD DO MANEVA 5INCO CABEAS','309','10'],['Santa Catarina, Brazil', 'St. Vincent - Brazilian Tour','321','28'],['Rua Voluntários da Pátria, Santana, São Paulo, Brazil', 'St. Vincent - Brazilian Tour','320','29']]
```

I'm passing the location to for loop to get the latitude and longitude to plot the markers in map. i'm using the following function

```
var markers = {};

function initial_markers(locations){
     for(var i=0;i<locations.length;i++){
        (function(address,attr_title,i,attr_id,cat_id) {
            console.log(i);
            geocoder.geocode({
               'address': address
            }, function(results) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                   map: map,
                   position: results[0].geometry.location,
                   icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"
                });
                markers[i] = marker;
                console.log(i); 
            });
        })(locations[i][0],locations[i][1],i,locations[i][2],locations[i][3]);  
    }
}
```

Totally 12 locations in that data. I get the 12 values before the function enters to geocode function. after the geocode it fails for the last element. and the order of i also changed. but its not problem for me. My problem is unable to get the latitude and longitude for the last location. and also unable to get the index. i'm using this index value for some other functions. The index value is stops in 10.  Please help to resolve this problem

Comment: Why didn't you add i to the internal function arguments ?

Comment: @dystory if i not add this it fails inside the loop. it returns the last element only

Comment: Where do you use the results ? Do you understand you can't use them right after the external function call ?

Comment: You have to check also the status of callback function. Most probably you get `OVER_QUERY_LIMIT` for some of requests.

Comment: @Anto Jurkovic i tried with the set timeout function. but it also returns the same result

Comment: How did you try it with a setTimeout function?  [You are definitely getting an OVER_QUERY_LIMIT](http://jsfiddle.net/xYvb6/1/).

Comment: @ geocodeZip is there any other wayto overcome the query Limit

Comment: A fiddle with a working `setInterval`: http://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/xYvb6/2/

Answer (score 0):

In order to preserve i, add it to the internal function arguments :

```
 (function(address,attr_title,i,attr_id,cat_id, i) {
        console.log(i);
        geocoder.geocode({
           'address': address
        }, function(results) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
               map: map,
               position: results[0].geometry.location,
               icon:"http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/blue.png"
            });
            markers[i] = marker;
            console.log(i);

            // NOTE : you should use markers HERE

        });
 })(locations[i][0],locations[i][1],i,locations[i][2],locations[i][3], i);
```

This way, you can also get rid of the other arguments...

Be careful to use the markers in the internal callback or in a function called from that callback (see NOTE).

Comment: @dystory Sorry. unable to get you. "you should use markers here" means need to plot the marker in that place?

Comment: Yes. When you call `initial_markers(locations)`, you can't use `markers` right after because the calls are asynchronous.

Comment: are you said that the function name is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

As Per Frank van Puffelen This is the correct solution for me. Thanks a lot Frank van Puffelen

```
    <http://jsfiddle.net/frankvanpuffelen/xYvb6/2/>
```